# How does a type indirectly refer to other functions base method?

Tags: function, types, interface, go

First of all, I am still not clear how to frame this question, but I am not able to understand, can someone help me in understanding this. Why does the below code errors out if I rename "serveHTTP" or not have that method.

```
prog.go:17: cannot use &status (type *statusHandler) as type http.Handler in argument to httptest.NewServer:
*statusHandler does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
[process exited with non-zero status]
```

for the below code

```
type statusHandler int

func (s *statusHandler) aServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println(" inside status handler serve http")
}

func main() {
    status := statusHandler(400)
    s := httptest.NewServer(&status)
    log.Println("value of s is %d", s)
    defer s.Close()
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/QZIrWALAm_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServeHTTP` is required to satisfy the [`http.Handler`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) interface.

```
type Handler interface {
        ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
}
```

> Interfaces in Go provide a way to specify the behavior of an object: if something can do this, then it can be used here.

See [Interfaces and Types in Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me, I verified where does `http.handler` used, and I see its a parameter for [httptest.NewServer](http://golang.org/src/net/http/httptest/server.go?s=2238:2282#L72) I understood that parameter passed should be of type & method should be included.

Comment: @KishoreVaishnav `http.Handler` can be used in many places. The most common would probably be the `http.Handle` (http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handle) function, but have a look at the index at http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/ and you will see that they are used in many other ways. They are the basic building block of many web services. They accept requests `http.Request`, do something with them , and then send a response on the `http.ResponseWriter`.

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/OEDetydMbW Actually I was trying to understand more, can you let me know why this doesn't really worries about CreateTable Function even it associated with Abc interface ?